# RESTful URI's, Creating a new noun/uri or add a queryparameter

Tags: http, rest, uri, data-modeling, restful-url

I have a Person class with a one to many relationship to Employment. A Person in the CRM can have multiple Employments (historic data).

My current REST URI for this class looks like this:

```
http://domain/persons GET [collection]
http://domain/persons/{id} GET [resource]
http://domain/persons/{id}/employments GET [collection]
```

To get the CURRENT active employment (so the employment where the endDate is NULL) should I create a URI or should this be done using a QueryParam?

Basically should I do this:

```
http://domain/persons/{id}/employments/current GET [resource]
```

or

```
http://domain/persons/{id}/employments?current GET [collection with query param filter]
```

I'm thinking the second one (with the queryparam) because as far as I understand REST a resource should be identified with a non changable URI. Since the current employment position can change it should be done with a QueryParam.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by identifying uniquely each employment like this:

`http://domain/persons/{id}/employments/{id} GET [resource]`

---

*Update according to comments info:*

When user calls `GET http://domain/persons/{id}/employments/`, she could be able to use a filter like `?state=current` which would return the resource that refers to the current employment and is uniquely identified by something like `http://domain/employments/{id}`.

Comment: No because that resource already exists at domain/employments/{id} so it would do a HTTP 303 to that current employment. I'm more talking about if "current employment" should be a NOUN in as a resource or a queryparameter as a filter

Comment: So when user calls `http://domain/persons/{id}/employments GET [collection]` he gets a list of the form `http://domain/employments/{id}`, right? Then, I think it should be a query parameter like `?state=current` and the response would be a `http://domain/employments/{id}` with the current employment.